# Confusion matrix for values labeled as TP, TN, FP, FN

Tags: python-3.x, confusion-matrix

I have a Pandas dataframe and want to draw a confusion matrix for a column.

The values of that column are strings already labeled as "False Negative", "False Positive", "True Negative", and "True Positive".

As these are not the typical True/False values, how can I generate a confusion matrix (similar to those generated by scikit-learn/matplotlib) with these values?

(Edited to clarify)
Assume that I have the following values in a column:

```
['True Positive', 'True Negative', 'False Positive', 'False Negative', 'True Negative', ..., True Positive', 'False Negative']
```

I can aggregate these values into total number of TP, TN, FP, FN. However, I would like to display a confusion matrix similar to the one generated by using the folowing:

```
disp = sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm)
disp = disp.plot(cmap="Blues")
matplot.lib.pyplot.plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Irina, please provide reproducible inputs for your questions. It's unfair to expect help without providing a piece of code that helps others generate the data you mention, refer [ask]. Also, please provide the expected output preferable with your attempt as well.

Comment: Thanks, @AkshaySehgal - Added more details. Hopefully this will help make the question clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to tackle this would be something like this :

```
TP = 0
TN = 0
FP = 0
FN = 0

for label in df.ColumnName:
    
    if label == "True Positive":
        TP  += 1
    elif label == "True Negative":
        TN += 1
    elif label == "False Positive":
        FP += 1
    else:
        FN += 1

print("Confusion Matrix : ")
print(f"[{TP}] [{FP}]")
print(f"[{FN}] [{TN}]")
```

Here `df` is the dataframe variable. thus we count the individual entries of the column and simply print the same.

Another much smaller way to do the same is as follows :

```
print(df['ColumnName'].value_counts()
```

Then to plot the values using the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [[TP, FP],[FN, TN]]
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data)
plt.colorbar(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you - Having these values, would it be possible to plot a graphical confusion matrix (similar to using ConfusionMatrixDisplay from sklearn.metrics, then disp.plot)?

Comment: No, you cannot do that since the ConfusionMatrixDisplay plots the ROC curve which is calculated for a model under training. We compute the value of True Positive Rate and False Positive Rates by varying the thresholds for classification. Thus trying to find the ROC for dataset does not make any sense. Also confusion matrix is an evaluation metric to analyze the performance of a model so I'm not sure why you wish to print it for the dataset. If this answer helped then please accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Currently, I am not looking to display the ROC curve; I am trying to display a matrix similar to this one: https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--v8krdHq4--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto%2Cw_880/https://thepracticaldev.s3.amazonaws.com/i/29erno9l9601wqb9zbqs.png

Comment: @Irina I have edited the answer to include the answer to plotting issue as well. If this is what you were looking for and it helped then do upvote and accept the answer. For any followup question please comment back.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to make it look like a typical confusion matrix (with the number s for each quadrant inside each square, 1/0 labels, and color?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For that please explore https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html or https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html